# How to make the child link directive function to run before parent controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code of the directive

```
.directive('directive',function(){
  return {
    link:function(scope){
      scope.a1='ok'
      scope.b1='ok'
      scope.c1='ok'
    }
  }
})
```

The code of the controller:

```
.controller('controller',function($scope,$timeout){
  $scope.a=$scope.a1
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.b=$scope.b1
  },100)
})
```

The result:

```
the scope.a1 ="" but needs to be 'ok' 
the scope.b = "ok" but needs to be 'ok' 
the scope.c1 = "ok" but needs to be 'ok'
```

Demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/80XojfqrrKNubi17TeHq?p=preview

---

I want that **a** to be ok. But when I declare it ($scope.a==$scope.a1) the directive link function didn't run yet.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make it similar to `$scope.b=$scope.b1`, put `$scope.a=$scope.a1` inside the `$timeout` function.

`$timeout` will delay the execution until next cycle. Then after the child directive is compiled, the assignment is done.

---

#### Update 1

If you don't want to use `$timeout`, you need to apply some async mechanism to delay the assignment (until the child directive finishes compilation). Such as, `$http.get(..).then()..`, etc.

Alternatively, put the assignment statement **inside** the child directive. Anyway, the parent and child use exactly the same `$scope` object.

Thirdly, use the `event` system to publish/subscribe events and call handlers.

Anyway, you need to ***delay*** the assignment statement in the parent through some async mechanism.

Comment: I prefer to not use $timeout. (I know how to use $timeout). I am searching for another solution please :)

Comment: @Amina Well, please check the answer update. Although I do not get what is the point of not using `$timeout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **$emit()** and **$on()**.

- **$emit()** dispatches the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.
- **$on()** listen specific event

So in your case you can do the following :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  //Listen for change event sent by the directive
  $scope.$on('change', function(){
    //Set our $scope value
    $scope.a = $scope.a1;
    $scope.b = $scope.b1;
  })

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function directive() {
    return {
      link:function(scope){
        scope.a1='ok';
        scope.b1='ok';
        scope.c1='ok';
        //Send change event
        scope.$emit('change');
      }
    };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('directive', directive);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div directive>
      the scope.a1 ="{{a}}" but needs to be 'ok'
      <br>
      the scope.b = "{{b}}" but needs to be 'ok'
      <br>
      the scope.c1 = "{{c1}}" but needs to be 'ok'
    </div>
  </body>
```

You can see the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/plvCUKml9TphEnkXhYd0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not possible (mainly if you consider that your template may contain asynchronous `ng-include` includes).

So what you need is sort of callback mechanism which will tell controller that something is loaded / ready. This can be achieved via multiple mechanisms:

1. Add `$watch` in your controller on some property set by the directive.
2. Call controller callback method from your directive.
3. Emit some event from your directive and listen for this event in the controller.

---

Which one to use really depends on the use-case. To give at least one example, here is the callback:

```
angular.module('foo', []).
controller('FooController', function() {
    this.init = function() {
        // Do some stuff
    };
}).
directive('foo', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.foo); // Call controller
        }
    };
});

<div ng-controller="FooController as fooController">
    <div foo="fooController.init()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but whata you tried to do "scope.$eval(attrs.foo)"?

Comment: I've passed script for the callback as directive parameter (`<div foo="fooController.init()">`). You can reference controller directly via scope if you don't want this kind of separation.